# Navigation Controller. Background color

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uibackgroundcolor

For one controller I have settings:

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

and

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        var offset = scrollView.contentOffset.y / 150
        if offset > 1 {
            offset = 1
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 82/255, green: 76/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: offset)
            UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 82/255, green: 76/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: offset)
            self.navigationItem.title = name
        } else {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 82/255, green: 76/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: offset)
             UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 82/255, green: 76/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: offset)
            self.navigationItem.title = ""
        }
    }
```

The main problem is that when i press back button, settings save. In the end i have white NavigationController. How can I make the settings not taken from the last controller?

```
func makeSearchController() {
        searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Блюдо или продукт ..."
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reset the navigation controller's color in `viewWillDisappear`, like this:

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 221/255, green: 221/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: offset) //gray color
    UIApplication.shared.statusBarView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 221/255, green: 221/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: offset) //gray color
}
```

Comment: it's amazing! it's work! And one more question. I have more searchController and he also stated without color. How i can him return color?

Comment: Could you share the code in which you changed the color of your searchController?

Comment: Your code `searchController.searchBar.tintColor = .white` makes your search bar white. To change it, your should either remove this line, or, when you want the change to apply, add a line `searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 221/255, green: 221/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: offset)`

Comment: This also makes the text white, not the controller itself. I have now figured out how to make it easier, but it seems to me that it's not quite beautiful. In viewWillAppear added searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor = UIColor (red: 82/255, green: 76/255, blue: 70/255, alpha: 1)